# ReactJS: How to trim label when it is a long text in material ui autocomplete

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, material-ui, frontend

I am using material UI autocomplete... I want to trim the label when it is a long text.

```
    <Autocomplete
      id="combo-box-demo"
      options={top100Films}
      getOptionLabel={(option) => option.title}
      style={{ width: 300 }}
      renderInput={(params) => 
      <TextField {...params} label="This is very long 
      labellllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllll" variant="outlined" />}
    />
```

[image]

Comment: You can use ```text-overflow: ellipsis``` in css for the class ```.MuiInputLabel-outlined.MuiInputLabel-shrink``` .. Working Example: https://codesandbox.io/s/material-ui-autocomplete-forked-p4fd1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the function `substring()`.

The method returns the part of the string between the start and end indexes, or to the end of the string.

```
const str = 'labelllllllllllll';

console.log(str.substring(0, 6));
// expected output: "label"

console.log(str.substring(2));
// expected output: "bel"
```

then in your Textfield you can use:

```
label={str.substring(0, 6)}
```